# Как сделать запрос к firebase на обновление данных методом FieldValue.arrayUnion

Tags: firebase

Есть запрос на изменение по полю likes  в коллекции  games, в firebase, 
где likes представляют собой массив, содержащий id  пользователей

```
like() {                  
        class DBwork {
          constructor(FirebaseVariable) {
            this.db = FirebaseVariable;
          }
          SetLike(game,user){
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              this.db.firestore().collection('games').doc(game).update({
                "likes": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user)
              })              
            });            
          }
        }     
        var variable = new DBwork(firebase); 
        variable.SetLike(this.game, this.currentUserId).then(r =>{
        console.log(r.data());
        });    
      }
```

Если первым аргументом передать экземпляр  игры  this.game,
это объект содержащий информацию по каждой игре получается ошибка:

Uncaught (in promise) 
FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() 
requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, 
but it was: a custom Object object

Если аргументом передать строку this.game.name ничего не происходит.

Какие-то мысли приходят насчет того, что  что этой записи:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
```

не хватает этой записи

```
var result=""
   resolve(result);
});
```

Но не пойму что и как правильно записать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример работающего запроса, хотя в firebase правила все время меняются и актуальность зависит от версии правил.

```
 like() {     

        class DBwork {
          constructor(FirebaseVariable) {
            this.db = FirebaseVariable;
          }

         async SetLike(game,user){
            var DocumentId = await new Promise(resolve => {
                this.db.firestore().collection('games').where('name','==',game).get().then(r=>{
                    resolve(r.docs[0].id)
                })
            });
            this.db.firestore().collection('games').doc(DocumentId).update({
                "likes": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user),
            })         

        }


        }  

      var variable = new DBwork(firebase);       
        variable.RemoveLike(this.game.name, user)
        .then(r =>{
             console.log(r.data());
       });

      }
```